# How to write a class library that will work on .NET 3.5 compact framework AND regular framework?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

How do I write a .NET class library that I can recompile for either the regular .NET 3.5 Framework, or the .NET 3.5 Compact Framework?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two frameworks aren't binary compatible*, unfortunately, but don't let that stop you.

Create two projects in your solution (one normal Class Library project, and one Compact Framework Class Library project), and add all the files from one project to the other *as links* by clicking "Add|Existing File" and then checking the "add as link" checkbox on the file dialog.

Now you only have one set of source code to maintain, but your solution will build both DLLs at the same time.

If you have any code inside a file that's specific to the desktop framework and won't work on the compact framework, you can wrap it in a compiler directive (at least in C#) like this:

```
#if PocketPC
    // mobile-specific stuff here
#else
    // desktop-specific stuff here
#endif
```

- Note that although you can't use desktop-framework binaries on a mobile platform, the opposite is not true. Compact framework executables can run on the desktop. I'm fairly certain, however, that a desktop application cannot reference a compact framework assembly (though I've never tried).

Comment: I've been successfully running desktop applikations - and ASP.Net sites - that reference compact framework assemblies for quite some time now. Seems like there is no problem with that what so ever...

Comment: Actually ... does that mean you have to install the Compact Framework on your target machines? Or do NETCF assemblies use the desktop framework if it's available?

Comment: No, Compact Framework does not need to be installed on the target machines. So the desktop assemblies must be used. As I remember it there was a quite comprehensive document on MSDN about this issue but I can't find it now...

Comment: Yes it just runs under the desktop edition of CLR. Therefore it is worth knowing about the differences between FF and CF if you're going to be sharing code between the two. I have a very incomplete list of these here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342576/do-you-know-any-run-time-differences-between-compact-and-full-framework-code

Answer (score 5):

> >
>   The two frameworks aren't binary compatible
>   >

Actually the Desktop version can load and run CF assemblies.

Comment: Ah yes that's true. +1 and I will amend my response.

Comment: dotnetcf3.5 is compatible with Desktopversion. In dotnetcf3.7 it is not any more but it is compatible with silverlight. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2010/03/18/comparing-windows-phone-with-net-compact-framework-3-5.aspx for details

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a class library for the
   compact framework.
2. Add a reference
   to that library from your .exe
   project (Desktop or Mobile)
3. Profit!

Seriously, I don't know why the top answer is so top. You don't need two separate projects at all. Also i'm not in love with pre-processor directives, they're ugly and require additional knowledge about the project when playing with the build parameters. It is much more pretty to outsource all the incompatible bits and pieces to an interface (IPlaformServices or such like) or you could even just ask:

```
   if(Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.WinCE)
   {
       // winCE specific     
   }
   else
   {
       // desktop specific
   }
```

Both of these are better solutions than preprocessor directives IMO.

Comment: Preprocessor directives mean that the code doesn't end up in the assembly if it's not required (or supported) on that platform. That's important on the compact framework where you want to keep your assemblies as small as possible.

Comment: Fair point. If disk space and memory are pressing concerns then use just one preprocessor command to generate your IPlatformServices. Having them littered throughout a code base can be hellish though so I don't recommend that route.