# Visual C++ project: best unit test setup

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, googletest

We have a pretty large C++ console application here which should now be unit tested via Googletest.

I thought it would be a good idea to store the unit tests and the test execution within a separate project. Both projects reside within the same solution.
As the application under test is compiled as an executable and not as a static library, I'm somewhat clueless on how to reference the implementation code from my unit tests within the test project.

I don't want to put all code files as existing items into the test project, also it would be alot of work to split the existing executable into a static library layer and a corresponding "wrapping" executable.

Long story short: any good ideas how to put an existing C++ executable project under test by using a separate test project? :)

To make the problem a bit harder: I have to use VS 2008 atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility I can think of is to add all the sources from the main project to the unit test project as a link:

[Visual Studio - how to create two projects using the same sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997489/visual-studio-how-to-create-two-projects-using-the-same-sources)

Second option would be to use a post-action in the main project and compile the main project or some part of it from the command line into a library which can be linked into the unit test project. This way one "build" action would produce an exe and a dll/lib file.

Third option, somehow combination the two options above: manage the unit test project outside of VS - compile the sources of the main project from a build script (simple batch file or scons, make, ant etc.) with the sources of the tests and execute from the command line.

Comment: Ok thank you. I think I'll go for the third approach and use some kind of build script.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be intersted by

- [Linker error - linking two "application" type projects in order to use Google Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283699/linker-error-linking-two-application-type-projects-in-order-to-use-google-te)
- [Linking to multiple .obj for unit testing a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496305/linking-to-multiple-obj-for-unit-testing-a-console-application/19710979#19710979)

It basically says that you don't touch your main project, add a post build action that aggregates your obj files into a static lib file.
Then you can link your test project with this static library.

It gives a lot of advantages in my opinion, like you don't modify your main project, the test project will be always up to date, ...