# Linking to multiple .obj for unit testing a console application

Tags: c++, linker, googletest

Having a few issues and hope I can find some help.

I have two projects under the same solution in Visual Studio 2012

A bit of background I cam creating a console application which outputs as a .exe this is in one project.

In another project I have google test set up to run unit tests on the classes in the console application project.

If I was able to compile the main project into a static library there wouldn't be an issue due to could link to the .lib, however this isn't an option.

I have found that linking to the .obj works however I need to manually enter each one into the linker -> input and due to there is going to be a large number of classes I can see this getting messy.

How do I solve this issue, is there a way of linking to all .obj in the same folder or is there an option I am missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the exact same configuration as yours and this is what I did:

I used the LIB utility of visual studio to put all .obj files into a .lib library, and then I could make my gtest project link to it.

Putting the command

```
lib /NOLOGO /OUT:"$(TargetPath).lib" "$(ProjectDir)\$(Configuration)\*.obj"
```

into the "Build events"/"Post-build Event" of your main project, you can keep your console application as a .exe and in the same time aggregate all your obj files to an up-to-date lib.

Hope it helps!

By the way, this problem is a bit similar to this post: [Linker error - linking two "application" type projects in order to use Google Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283699/linker-error-linking-two-application-type-projects-in-order-to-use-google-te) and I think it could be usefull to link it here.

Comment: I'm glad I came across this. Very useful answer. As of VS 2022 the paths didn't quite work out for me. I adjusted it like so: `lib /NOLOGO /OUT:"$(OutDir)$(AssemblyName).lib" "$(IntDirFullPath)*.obj"`, though I can't say that it'll work for others as well.